# Data from HTML table going NULL to database

Tags: php, mysql, null

This is my form:

```
<form method="post" action="insert.php">

            <label>Download Name:<br /><input type="textbox" id="name" name="name"></label><br /><br />
            <label>Download Description:<br /><textarea rows="3" id="description" name="description"></textarea></label><br /><br />
            <label>Category:<br /><input type="textbox" id="category" name="category"><br/></label><br /><br />
            <label>Download Link:<br /><input type="textbox" id="link" name="link"><br/></label><br /><br />

        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Insert"/>
```

This is my insert.php:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
$description = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['description']);
$category = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['category']);
$link = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['link']);

$sql="INSERT INTO test (name, description, category, link)
VALUES ('$name', '$description', '$category', '$link')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This is my sql:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
description varchar(255),
category varchar(255),
link varchar(255)
)
```

What is happening is the user fills the form. The input is sent to insert.php where it connects to the database and inserts it into the dabase.

What is happening is that it is connecting successfully but my records are empty.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What does `echo $sql` show?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO test (name, description, category, link)
VALUES ("'.$name.'", "'.$description.'", "'.$category.'", "'.$link.'")';


$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if (!$result)
  die('Error: '.mysqli_error($con));
else
{
    echo '1 record added';

    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

What about this?